# User defined environment: article vs book

Tags: environments

For LaTeX-submitted articles (e.g. journal papers)
I have a very simple Remark environment:

```
\newcounter{remarkno}%
\renewcommand{\theremarkno}{\arabic{remarkno}}%
\newenvironment{remark}{\small%
   \refstepcounter{remarkno}%
   \noindent\textbf{Remark~\theremarkno}.%
   \par}%
{}%
```

This definition numbers remarks 1,2,... over the whole article.
I would like to extend this to a textbook under preparation
so that the Remark labels for Chapter 3, say, are 3.1, 3.2,...
Question: assuming amsmath is loaded, would it be enough to
change  \renewcommand to

```
\renewcommand{\theremarkno}{\arabic{\numberwithin{remarkno}{chapter}}}
```

N.B. This change would be needed for 6 more environments, namely
exercise, solution, datedremark, myfootnote, chapternotes, comment.
So the above replacement, if it works, would be easily replicated.
And only standard LaTeX 2.0 would be needed. (My experience is that
inserting newer packages often breaks code).

Answer (score 1):

Make an abstraction.

```
\documentclass{article} % or book

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newnumberedenvironment}[3]{%
  \newcounter{#1}%
  \newenvironment{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  \@ifundefined{chapter}{}{\counterwithin{#1}{chapter}}%
}
\makeatother
\newnumberedenvironment{remark}{\small%
   \refstepcounter{remark}%
   \noindent\textbf{Remark~\theremark}.%
   \par}%
{}%
\newnumberedenvironment{solution}{...}{...}
\newnumberedenvironment{datedremark}{...}{...}
\newnumberedenvironment{myfootnote}{...}{...}
\newnumberedenvironment{chapternotes}{...}{...}
\newnumberedenvironment{comment}{...}{...}

\begin{document}

\begin{remark}
Something
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I change `article` into `book` and add `\chapter{Test}`, I get

[image]

It's a bit more complicated if you want to support arguments for the new environments.

```
\documentclass{book} % or book

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newnumberedenvironment}[1]{%
  \def\numberedenv@name{#1}%
  \@newnumberedenvironment
}
\newcommand{\@newnumberedenvironment}[3][0]{%
  \newcounter{\numberedenv@name}%
  \newenvironment{\numberedenv@name}[#1]{#2}{#3}%
  \@ifundefined{chapter}{}{%
    \expandafter\counterwithin\expandafter{\numberedenv@name}{chapter}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newnumberedenvironment{remark}{\small%
   \refstepcounter{remark}%
   \noindent\textbf{Remark~\theremark}.%
   \par}%
{}%
\newnumberedenvironment{solution}{...}{...}
\newnumberedenvironment{datedremark}{...}{...}
\newnumberedenvironment{myfootnote}{...}{...}
\newnumberedenvironment{chapternotes}{...}{...}
\newnumberedenvironment{comment}{...}{...}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\begin{remark}
Something
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```